# Replace Django ManyToMany fields with chained strings or convert to first normal form

Tags: django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many

Suppose that I have a Position table that specifies a user's position (leader, assistant, member, ...):

```
class Position(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=20)
```

A document has a title and  privileges, namely, create, modify, and so on. We may specify which user positions may perform which privileges; e.g., a leader or an assistant may create a document:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=50)
    create = ManyToManyField(Position)
    modify = ManyToManyField(Position)
    ...
```

Of course, the above arrangement is not acceptable in Django because there should be only one `ManyToManyField` in a model.

I wonder which one of the followings is a better solution:

(a) Chain the positions (provided the number of positions are not great and the position data will not change):

```
class = Document(...):
    ...
    create = CharField(max_length=100)
    modify = CharField(max_length=100)
```

where `create` may be `leader-assistance-member`, which means a leader, an assistance, or a member may create a document. All we have to do is to split the string to obtain a list of positions.

(b) Convert to 1NF:

```
class = Document(...)
    title = ...

class Create(...):
    document = ForeignKey(Document)
    position = ForeignKey(Position)

class Modify(...):
    document = ForeignKey(Document)
    position = ForeignKey(Position)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but per [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield), you could have multiple many-to-many fields referencing the same model. You'd just need to specify a related_name to differentiate them.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    create = models.ManyToManyField(Position, related_name='create_positions')
    modify = models.ManyToManyField(Position, related_name='modify_positions')
    ...
```